# Google maps - directions service api ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, directions

I have a question regarding directions service API. Is there a hybrid travel mode setting which would allow me to draw a route for a bike, even if there isn't a bike track on that particular street or it's against street rules (is it even possible).
I would like to draw a segment which will go from A to B exactly through selected road, and not around if that road
doesn't actually allow driving in that direction. It doesn't have to be correct in regard to driving rules, it must be just drawn over the street. I tried bicycle mode instead of driving mode, but there isn't any difference.

I hope my post makes any sense

[image: In blue is route made by google, I need route in yellow]

Example of call:

```
function loadRoute0() {
  var request0 = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(46.56300788, 15.62779705),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(46.55953332, 15.62616729),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING
  };

  directionsService.route(request0, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#00FF00"
        },
        suppressMarkers: true,
        map: map
      });
      renderer.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TravelMode.WALKING`, that tends to give results for one way roads and other routes that won't work for `TravelMode.DRIVING`.
The code in your question doesn't reproduce the picture you posted, but using `TravelMode.WALKING` returns a route (where `TravelMode.BICYCLING` gives `ZERO_RESULTS` for the posted code)

```
function loadRoute0() {
  var request0 = {
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(46.56300788, 15.62779705),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(46.55953332, 15.62616729),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  };
  directionsService.route(request0, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        polylineOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#00FF00"
        },
        suppressMarkers: true,
        map: map
      });
      renderer.setDirections(result);
    } else
      console.log("status=" + status);
  });
}
```

- [proof of concept fiddle (for the posted code)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4hmqx2v6/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

- [proof of concept fiddle (for the picture)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4hmqx2v6/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  loadRoute0();

  function loadRoute0() {
    var request0 = {
      origin: new google.maps.LatLng(46.56300788, 15.62779705),
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(46.55953332, 15.62616729),
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    };
    var markerS = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: request0.origin,
      map: map,
      label: "S"
    });
    var markerE = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: request0.destination,
      map: map,
      label: "E"
    });
    directionsService.route(request0, function(result, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          polylineOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#00FF00"
          },
          suppressMarkers: true,
          map: map
        });
        renderer.setDirections(result);
      } else
        console.log("status=" + status);
    });
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```